# How do I safely convert a double into an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, int, double

Is there a way to convert a double into an integer without risking any undesired errors in the process? I read in Programming - Principles and Practice Using C++ (a book written by the creator of c++) that doubles cannot be turned into integers, but I've put it to the test, and it converts properly about 80% of the time. What's the best way to do this with no risk at all, if it's even possible?

So for example, this converts properly.

```
double bruh = 10.0;
int a = bruh;
cout << bruh << "\n";
```

But this doesn't.

```
double bruh = 10.9;
int a = bruh;
cout << bruh << "\n";
```

In short, it doesn't round automatically so I think that's what constitutes it as "unsafe".

Comment: Maybe you should show what you mean. Obviously if the double is larger than the maximum integer it won't work.

Comment: Both of your examples work. The rule is the fractional part is thrown away.

Comment: C++ gets a lot of behavior from C.  Your "...without risking any undesired errors..." doesn't make sense to me, because the behavior is known.  There are functions to do the conversion from double to int that give you more control over the conversion.  You can write your own routines to do the conversions, and provide `assert` or `throw` exception if it fails whatever constraints you impose.

Comment: @drescherjm "if the double is larger than the maximum integer it won't work." is not quite true.  The allowable `double` range is a bit more.  `INT_MIN-0.999...` to `INT_MAX+0.999...`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the risk is that you are trying to avoid. Can you explain?

Comment: Not being pedantic, but what do you mean by "safely", "properly", "undesired", and "risk"? There's no one correct way to convert a double to an integer. Only the way that you want for your application. (okay well I *am* being pedantic but we need to be pedantic to figure out what you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it not possible to convert all doubles to integers with no risk of losing data.

First, if the double contains a fractional part (42.9), that fractional part will be lost.

Second, doubles can hold a much larger range of values than most integers, something around 1.7e308, so when you get into the larger values you simply won't be able to store them into an integer.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure the double atleast rounds up when converting it? Assuming the double isn't larger than the maximum size of the integer.

Comment: `std::round` may be a place to start. There is also `std::ceil` and `std::floor`

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, thanks. I haven't tried the round function yet but I'll see if it works for me.

Comment: @Anthony I wouldn't try the function, I would read some documentation on it to see if it does what you want. From want you have described so far I would say that `ceil` is what you want.

Comment: @john In this scenario, is `ceil` better than `round`? Wouldn't they perform the exact same thing?

Comment: @Anthony `ceil` rounds up, `round` rounds to the nearest which could be up or down.

Comment: @john oh, so it's better to make the function more specific. Alright, thanks.

Comment: The interesting thing is in my day job I rarely need to use either of these. >99% of the time truncation is all I want. However like others said the conversion you want to apply depends on your application.

Answer (score 1):

> way to convert a double into an integer without risking any undesired errors
> in short, it doesn't round automatically so I think that's what constitutes it as "unsafe"

To convert to an integer value:

```
x = round(x);
```

To convert to an integer type:

Start with a round function like `long lround(double x);`. It "Returns the integer value that is nearest in value to x, with halfway cases rounded away from zero."

If the round result is outside the `long` range, problems occur and code may want to test for that first.

```
// Carefully form a double the is 1 more than LONG_MAX
#define LONG_MAXP1 ((LONG_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0)

long val = 0;
if (x - LONG_MAXP1 < -0.5 && x - LONG_MIN > -0.5) {
  val = lround(x);
} else {
  Handle_error();
}
```

---

Detail: in order to test if a `double` is in range to round to a `long`,  it is important to test the endpoints carefully.  The mathematical valid range is `(LONG_MIN-0.5 ... LONG_MAX + 0.5)`, yet those endpoints may not be exactly representable as a `double`.  Instead code uses nearby  `LONG_MIN` and `LONG_MAXP1` whose magnitudes are powers of 2 and easy to represent exactly as a `double`.